# Selenium Chrome Driver opens a different page than regular Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to pull some information from this URL and ones like it: "https://www.rockymountainatvmc.com/tires-and-wheels/tusk-impact-complete-wheel-rear-p?s=1033997&v=1216"

My goal is to get the MSRP and other info for a specific part. To do this, I'm using python to run a selenium chrome webdriver that opens several of these URLs. The problem is the links aren't opening with the same information that I would get in my regular Chrome browser.

The link is supposed to contain all the information to "select a vehicle" and thus a specific part. When I open this in my regular chrome browser, everything works fine. When I open this using the automated Chrome page, it fails to select a vehicle and shows a general part page.

I can't figure out what the difference might be between these two browsers that would cause this. My regular chrome browser and the chromedriver are both version 81.0.4044.113. I've tried going to whatismybrowser.com and all settings are identical. Another interesting thing is opening this in internet explorer gives me the same result as the automated chrome browser. Help!

[regular chrome browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaWRm.png)

[automated chrome browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0dmw.png)

Answer (score 1):

The Regular chrome browser is fetching the details of your bike(Something -- yamaha 125). It could be from past cookies or cache.

However, once you are opening it with Automation, a clean session s opened.

Try cleaning your cookies and cache on the browser(regular) and then try, both of them should appear same.

Or you can use options in chrome to select the profile your regular chrome browser is using. See https://startingwithseleniumwebdriver.blogspot.com/2015/07/working-with-chrome-profile-with.html.

Hope it Helps!

Comment: Hi Kumar. I appreciate the reply. I know the details for the bike isn't coming from my cookies or cache. I have a a bunch of these links and each one opens a different bike selection. I tried adding my user profile to the automated chrome with no luck. I even tried using a firefox browser and still no luck.

Comment: Can you try manually in an incognito mode and let me know what are you seeing? Is that same to that what of automated chrome browser. Well different DOM for same page doesn't make sense unless cookies or cache comes into place.